# Reduce Nondeterminism in Pushdown Automata

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

I know there might be some situations where we want transitions to be only taken when the stack is empty, and transitions to be taken only when the input stream is empty.

We can create an additional start state, and push a special key like "#" on the stack to start. We can also append the input stream with a "$" so we can use that as a transition symbol.

However, I'm trying to visualize this. I would want to change an existing PDA and make it less nondeterministic. I can't come up with a machine that would show this benefit.

Comment: What these additional symbols have to do with your question? What do you mean by reducing nondeterminism? PDA and NPDA are not equivalent in power, so such "reduce of nondeterminism" will not be possible in many cases.

Comment: I agree, I don't understand what the question is. Community votes, please: unclear?